# Add Custom font to GUI SWT

Tags: java, fonts, swt

I am trying to add a new custom font to a GUI.
i added the .tff file to my java project but didn't succeed to use it. here is my code:

```
  Font font = new Font(shell.getDisplay(), "A.ttf", 12, SWT.NORMAL);
  myText.setFont(font);
```

Note: I can use only SWT. Does anyone know how to install the new font?
Thanks!

Comment: Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: Thanks! working good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to load the font first to make it available to the application:

```
boolean isFontLoaded = shell.getDisplay().loadFont("A.ttf");

if(isFontLoaded)
{
    Font font = new Font(shell.getDisplay(), "name of the font", 12, SWT.NORMAL);
    myText.setFont(font);
}
```

Remeber to dispose the `Font` again, when you're done using it.